# simple TCP socket chat server doesn't work on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I wanted to build a node.js chat server on heroku, the chat clients are going to be iOS apps.

My first attempt is to build a server based on socket.io. It works, but I don't like the fact the the iOS app is talking to the server using long polling instead of websocket or tcp socket.

So my second attempt is to build the server using real TCP socket, code as below:

```
var net = require('net');

var sockets = [];

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        for(var i=0; i< sockets.length; i++)
        {
            sockets[i].write(data);
        }
    });
    socket.on('end', function() {
        var i  = sockets.indexOf(socket);
        sockets.splice(i, 1);
    })
});

var port  = process.env.PORT || 5000;
console.log("server listening to port " + port);
server.listen(port);
```

If I deploy this node.js server code in localhost, i can successfully send and receives chat  to the TCP server using Terminal as test client

```
nc localhost 5000
```

BUT, if I deploy this server code in heroku, I couldn't establish a tcp connection with the server anymore.

My understanding is server will be listening at the process.env.PORT.

So I first traced out this port that the server is listening, e.g. 30134.

Then If I attempt to connect in this way:

```
nc http://my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com 30134
```

Nothing happens.

I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. Can anyone guide me? Is Real TCP  socket chat possible on heroku server?

Comment: What is the content of your `Procfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku does not support websocket.  This is why, for example, `socket.io` needs to be forced to use `xhr-polling`.  (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).

Instead of using sockets directly, you could use something like `socket.io` which supports multiple transports.

This is because they use and older version of `nginx`, which did not have full web socket support.

Plus, the port your app is listening on, `e.g. 30134` is proxied by nginx from your heroku hostname on port 80 to your app port on heroku's internal network.

Comment: well HTTP is TCP. I suppose the only incovenient is that nginx will timeout the request at some point. If you really need TCP, you can maybe bypass this by giving nginx a CONNECT method.

Comment: hi pascal, i am aware that real web socket is not supported in heroku.  As mentioned in my question, i have tried socket.io before, it works, but I don't like the fact that long poll might be slow compare to a TCP socket server? not websocket, but the raw TCP socket?

Comment: nginx is geared towards http only, and enough to support some http/1.1, but not enough to suport plain tcp.  Especially in the sense that it is stateless.  Recent update that add support for websocket is a plus, but still not enough to support plain tcp connections.  So you should use something that can pass through heroku's front end (nginx).

Comment: hi pascal, thanks for the tips that heroku doesn't support plain tcp connections. If i need to setup a server tat support plain tcp connections, do you have any suggestion? Amazon?

Comment: EC2 is a better options, although there may be some issues with their load balancer, but you can do plain tcp connections (like ssh for example).

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late to this party but I wrote an addon to route raw TCP sockets into Heroku ( https://addons.heroku.com/ruppells-sockets ) to support a project I was working on. It's very much beta so be gentle.

If you still need this functionality I'd be keen to get some feedback.
The documentation for the addon links to an example nodejs TCP and Websocket chat server for inspiration.

Comment: Shoot, I'm very late the party. Is this discontinued? The link returns a 404

Comment: not as late as I am to reply. I'm afraid it's discontinued, I didn't have the bandwidth to maintain the addon. If your use case is websockets on heroku I think that's now supported fully by the Heroku router